# Watcher textEdit with Fragment - Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, textwatcher

I'm doing one app to make some maths, so in this test I can write one value and the app automatically converts it to another unit, and the reverse too, so with 2 textEdits I write a number in any of it that the other gets the value converted. Only this code works perfectly in a separated app.
Now I found in this link:
https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample 
a nice layout with sliding menus from left, its about percentLayout, but actually I dont need it, I just like that layout :)

Well, in differents app the codes are working well, but when I try to put the code with the Watcher in this new laoyt, it doest works;
I just put the values of my layout in the view1.xls and then create one view_1.java, with all the necessary codes;

Should I add something to make the Watcher work inside the fragment ?

view_1.java

```
public class view_1 extends Activity {

    double CVtokWfactor_2 = 0.7354988;
    boolean doNotEnterEd1 = false;
    boolean doNotEnterEd2 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view1);

        final EditText ed1_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText02_1);
        final EditText ed2_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText02_2);


        ed1_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (doNotEnterEd1 == true) {
                    return;
                }
                doNotEnterEd1 = true;

                try {
                    if (ed1_2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        ed2_2.setText("");
                    } else {
                        ed2_2.setText(String.format("%.3f", (Double.parseDouble(ed1_2.getText().toString()) * CVtokWfactor_2)));
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                doNotEnterEd2 = false;

            }
        });

        ed2_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                if (doNotEnterEd2 == true) {
                    return;
                }

                doNotEnterEd1 = true;
                try {
                    if (ed2_2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        ed1_2.setText("");
                    } else {
                        ed1_2.setText(String.format("%.3f", (Double.parseDouble(ed2_2.getText().toString()) * CVtokWfactor_2)));    //Here do the conversion as you like, replace CVtokWfactor.
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }

                doNotEnterEd1 = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
        });


    }


}
```

and the view1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.juliengenoud.percentsamples.view_1">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText02_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Potência CV"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText02_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText02_1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Potência kW"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What do you think I would do to make it work ? If you guys have any link of a similar reference, please show me.

Thanks very much!
Barata